# React app render function executes before state is set?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a chatting app in React, but it crashes right after sending a message. Here is part of the code

```
state ={
    conversationData: null,
    message: ''
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({conversationData: this.props.conversationData});
};

onSendClicked = () => {
    con.addMessage(this.state.conversationData.id, data).then(() => {
        this.setState({message: ''}, () => {
            this.setState({conversationData: this.state.conversationData.message.push(data)});
        });
    });
};
```

and in my render function, I have this

```
   <List>
         {this.state.conversationData.message !== null && this.state.conversationData.message !== undefined ? 
this.state.conversationData.message.map((mes, index)
........ 
: <div/>....
```

The problem is in that loop, it works fine when I load it, but once I press send message and set the state on `conversationData`, it either returns an empty `div` and never updates or crashes with `.map()` is undefined if I eliminate that `div`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First off you're mutating state with that push, which you should never do also why do you have nested setStates? why not just update both in the first setState?

Comment: Second, array.push returns the length of the array and not the array with the new element added.

Comment: yes, already figured that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current code this is how I would set it up:

```
state ={
    conversationData: this.props.conversationData, // no need to set it as null then update on mount
    message: ''
};

onSendClicked = () => {
    con.addMessage(this.state.conversationData.id, data).then(() => {
        this.setState(({ conversationData }) => ({
            message: '',
            conversationData: { 
              ...conversationData,
              message: [ ...conversationData.message, data ] // where is this data coming from?
            } // update conversationData with message
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that was actually a stupid mistake, as conversationData is an object and I assigned a number to it by doing that push. But even though the state updates correctly, I don't see any changes on the screen, which should probably happen as render function gets called

Comment: I see, I updated my answer to work more closely to what you're looking for but where is this `data` coming from? its not defined anywhere

Comment: Data is just an object that is constructed before calling addMessage. But your solution does exactly what I need. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

assuming that 'con' is defined and has a method named 'addMessage' that isn't returning an error

i'm also assuming that you have a type-o and data is being passed in from onSendClicked(data)

then i would do this. take special notice to the spread operator

`[...this.state.conversationData.message, data.id]`

as opposed to mutating state with .push()

as well as initializing conversationData.message state with an [] to avoid iteration errors on null (check for conversationData.message.length instead of conversationData.message !== null)

```
state ={
    conversationData: {message:[]},
    message: ''
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({conversationData: this.props.conversationData});
};

onSendClicked = (data) => {
    con.addMessage(this.state.conversationData.id, data)
        .then(() => {
            this.setState({
                message: '',
                conversationData: [...this.state.conversationData.message, data]
            })
        });
};
```

in render:

```
<List>
         {
             this.state.conversationData.message.length && this.state.conversationData.message.map((mes, index)=>{
                  //dosomething with mes and index
             })
         }
</List>
```